# An HTML input box overshoots its containing div on the right margin, why?

Tags: html, css

A div containing an input box, both set to width: 100%, and the input box overshoots the div by a little bit on the right margin. Why?

```html
<div style="border: 1px dashed grey; padding: 50px;">
 <div style="border: 1px solid green; width: 100%; padding: 20px 0 20px 0">
  <input style="border: 1px dotted red; width: 100%;" placeholder="placeholder">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This happening because how browsers calculate dimensions of a div. Add this to your css - "box-sizing: border-box". This will make everything work expected. Your issue was caused due to the paddings you have given. You can read more about box-sizing here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: I completely forgot about border-box, thanks for that. I added it to my answer but don't hesitate to make your own

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the input is lacking a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). That’s very important for users in general, and users with disabilities in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you declare the box-sizing so it adjusts to the border box?

In HTML, unless specified, the padding, border and content are not included in the total space that the element takes in the page. This means, that as default, the size specified by the element in the style (HTML or CSS) is exclusively for the content, so the padding and border will take extra space.

Here's a pic of a drawing I just made explaining the difference between box and content sizing in HTML/CSS:

[box-sizing in HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT4kx.png)

So in order to avoid that, you either want to:

1. Manually take into account the padding, border width and content width so that all of them together make 100% (which is hard, and you need to count that padding and border if not just one sided are usually doubled %).
2. Or adjust the box-sizing to the border:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I personally recommend the 2nd one because you don't need to be calculating anything else, but in case you don't want to use it, maybe you could use the function 'calc()' to make it easier.

Finally, unasked but, I would recommend you to avoid using so many  and styling in CSS instead of inside the HTML.

There's many block type html elements (aside, section, article, fieldset) that are more specific semantically and ultimately learning those might be the difference between good and bad HTML practices.

Comment: Yes that's it. And to be fair the first one to give this answer was @AnasMohammadSheikh.  Of course I use CSS stylesheets, I just made the style explicit in my example so it was easy to see.

Comment: I don't know what you are implying, but I didn't see it, I just wanted to explain it in a detailed way so you understand it.

Answer (score 1):

It happens for two reasons :

- The input has a default padding set by the browser
- 2px are added by the border

**Edit**

As [Anas Mohammad Sheikh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18045679/anas-mohammad-sheikh) mentioned in comment, you can fix it by setting `box-sizing:border-box`

```css
.container {
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  padding: 50px;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

input {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <input placeholder="placeholder">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Previous answer**

Here I removed the padding with `padding: 0` and reduced the input with by 2 * border size (for left and right).

```css
.container {
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  padding: 50px;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

input {
  --border: 1px;
  border: var(--border) dotted red;
  width: calc(100% - 2 * var(--border));
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <input placeholder="placeholder">
  </div>
</div>
```

In the example `width: calc(100% - 2 * var(--border))` is the same as `width: calc(100% - 2px)`

Note : `padding: 20px 0 20px 0` is the same as `padding: 20px 0`